# Ask for a reqular expression to remove prefix or suffix from a string in Oracle

Tags: regex, plsql, oracle11g

I want to remove prefix or suffix from a string, the string looked like below:
`L-CHGSUP-CDO-BR-NET|MS COORDINATOR X|MS COORDINATOR Z|` or
`|L-CHGSUP-CDO-BR-NET|MS COORDINATOR X|MS COORDINATOR Z|||`
I want to remove delimiter `|` in the end or beginning of the string and in the final, the string should be looked like this:
`L-CHGSUP-CDO-BR-NET|MS COORDINATOR X|MS COORDINATOR Z`

So, how to write a regular expression to do this in PLSQL?

Comment: [TRIM](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/to_URL?remark=ranked&urlname=http:%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fcd%2FE11882_01%2Fserver.112%2Fe41084%2Ffunctions219.htm%23SQLRF06149)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regular expression does the job:

```
select regexp_replace('|L-CHGSUP-CDO-BR-NET|MS COORDINATOR X|MS COORDINATOR Z|||','(^[\|]*)|[\|]*$') from dual
```

Answer (score 1):

As EatÅPeach suggested, you don't need to use a regular expression for this, the built-in [`TRIM` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions219.htm) will do:

```
select trim('|' from '|L-CHGSUP-CDO-BR-NET|MS COORDINATOR X|MS COORDINATOR Z|||')
from dual;

TRIM('|'FROM'|L-CHGSUP-CDO-BR-NET|MSCOORDINATORX|MSCOORDINATORZ|||')
--------------------------------------------------------------------
L-CHGSUP-CDO-BR-NET|MS COORDINATOR X|MS COORDINATOR Z
```

Or if you already have the value and want to trim it within PL/SQL (as a contrived example):

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  old_value varchar2(80);
  new_value varchar2(80);
begin
  old_value := '|L-CHGSUP-CDO-BR-NET|MS COORDINATOR X|MS COORDINATOR Z|||';
  new_value := trim('|' from old_value);
  dbms_output.put_line(new_value);
end;
/

anonymous block completed
L-CHGSUP-CDO-BR-NET|MS COORDINATOR X|MS COORDINATOR Z
```